# Why does GMail ignore this Microdata for a restaurant reservation?

Tags: html, gmail, google-schemas

This is example of the Microdata which is attached in every email I send out to a customer:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishmentReservation">
  <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="123456"/>
  <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
  <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Test Tester"/>
    <meta itemprop="email" content="test@example.org"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="My Venue" />
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://example.org/venues/images/1.jpg" />
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="123, My address, City, Country" />
      <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="City" />
      <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="City" />
      <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="Country" />
      <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="12345" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="startTime" content="2021-10-12T17:00:00+02:00"/>
  <meta itemprop="bookingTime" content="2021-10-05T00:08:00+02:00"/>
  <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2021-10-05T00:08:00+02:00"/>
  <meta itemprop="partySize" content="2"/>
</div>
```

This validates in [their tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/), but it still doesn't show up opening the email. Is there anything that stands out being wrong?

TYIA

Comment: The sending account is the same as the receiving account? (I'm also not able to send these to myself.)

Comment: Managed to get the emails validated by Google, I posted an answer to this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation extensively I finally found a page in their documentation explaining the entire process. We completed every step and our emails are now accepted by Google and now properly creates the visualisation when someone opens our email in GMail.

The documentation of all things required can be found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

The most important part is that you need to complete the step:

> - Fill out the [registration form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfT5F1VJXtBjGw2mLxY2aX557ctPTsCrJpURiKJjYeVrugHBQ/viewform?pli=1) and we will get back to you.

After properly filling out the form, you will have to wait ca 48 hours before a representative from Google will contact you.

Comment: Did you get the visualisations to appear before going through the registration form? (I have perfectly valid microcode that doesn't show up, even when sender & receiver are exactly the same Gmail account.)

Comment: No, I never managed to get them showing while testing. I validated my code in their tester and then I followed their instructions listed on the website and their form. If you want to change values after wards you can do so without being cleared again, it seems that their whitelisting covers all different schemas as well.